# How to group and sum by multiple conditions in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
expiration_date  payment_date   amount_payed
    
2019-01          2019-02        100.00
2019-01          2019-03        50.00
2019-02          2019-05        150.00
2019-03          2019-06        150.00
2019-04          2019-08        40.00
2019-04          2019-08        110.00
2019-05          2019-09        150.00
2019-06          2019-10        150.00
```

What I want to do is to group all the transactions by `payment_date`, and sum the `amount_payed`. Now knowing how much the client payed each month, I want to make a column `month` that starts at the first value of `expiration_date` and ends in the last value of `payment_date`. At the end it should look something like this:

```
month        total_amount_payed
    
2019-01      0.00
2019-02      100.00
2019-03      50.00
2019-04      0.00
2019-05      150.00
2019-06      150.00
2019-07      0.00
2019-08      150.00
2019-09      150.00
2019-10      150.00
```

What I've done so far is to use the `aggregate()` function like so:

```
aggregate(amount_payed~payment_date, dataframe, sum)
```

Which works fine and leaves my dataset looking like this:

```
month        total_amount_payed
    
2019-02      100.00
2019-03      50.00
2019-05      150.00
2019-06      150.00
2019-08      150.00
2019-09      150.00
2019-10      150.00
```

Now what I can't figure out is how to add the missing dates where the client didn't make any payment and fill those with 0.00.

Keep in mind this is just a sample set for one client, the original data set has many clients and I should do this for each one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(payment_date = as.Date(as.yearmon(payment_date))) %>% 
   summarise(total_amount_payed = sum(amount_payed)) %>% 
   complete(payment_date = seq(floor_date(min(payment_date), 'year'),
      max(payment_date), by = '1 month'),
         fill = list(total_amount_payed = 0)) %>%
   mutate(payment_date = format(payment_date, "%Y-%m"))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   payment_date total_amount_payed
#   <chr>                     <dbl>
# 1 2019-01                       0
# 2 2019-02                     100
# 3 2019-03                      50
# 4 2019-04                       0
# 5 2019-05                     150
# 6 2019-06                     150
# 7 2019-07                       0
# 8 2019-08                     150
# 9 2019-09                     150
#10 2019-10                     150
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(expiration_date = c("2019-01", "2019-01", "2019-02", 
"2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-04", "2019-05", "2019-06"), payment_date = c("2019-02", 
"2019-03", "2019-05", "2019-06", "2019-08", "2019-08", "2019-09", 
"2019-10"), amount_payed = c(100, 50, 150, 150, 40, 110, 150, 
150)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: This actually works quite well. But it will work if for instance I have a person_id also? So I should group by person_id + expiration_date and then complete it. I'm trying to avoid using a for loop since my dataset it's big.

Comment: @mrTito if there is more groups, then add those in the `group_by` i.e. `group_by(person_id, payment_date`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reference dataframe with the `payment_date` that you want in final dataframe before using `aggregate`.

```
ref_df <- data.frame(payment_date = sprintf('2019-%02d', 1:10))

aggregate(amount_payed~payment_date, merge(df, ref_df, all.y = TRUE), 
          sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = 'na.pass')

#   payment_date amount_payed
#1       2019-01            0
#2       2019-02          100
#3       2019-03           50
#4       2019-04            0
#5       2019-05          150
#6       2019-06          150
#7       2019-07            0
#8       2019-08          150
#9       2019-09          150
#10      2019-10          150
```